# Possible to access an array with index at memory address?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I am currently accessing an array like this:

```
ARRAY:   .long 1,2,3,4
# put index in register ebx
mov $4, %ebx
# put nums value in eax
mov nums(,%ebx,4), %eax
```

Is it possible to, instead of using a register for the array to use an address on the stack? For example if I have the value `4` stored at `%rbp-4`, something like:

```
mov nums(-4,%rbp,4)
```

Comment: No.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes for a rundown of x86-64 addressing modes.  There is no "doubly indirect" addressing mode like this.  You'll have to load the index into another register first.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: `nums-4(,%rbp,4)` is a valid addressing mode but it doesn't access memory twice.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you please clarify what you mean by 'it doesnt access twice' ?

Comment: I mean it's not double-indirection like you want.  It calculates an address based on registers and the constant displacement, `[num - 4 + rbp*4]`, and accesses memory once at that address.  I just found it weird that you thought that your almost-valid syntax of mov from `nums(-4,%rbp,4)` might do 2 loads, because the valid version of that syntax doesn't.